# Get content of a page in IRB (within debugger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, irb

I have a failing test for my Rails project (where a certain piece content is supposed to appear on the page, but is not), and I'm trying to debug it using the `debugger` gem. Because I see what I think is correct content when I view a page in the browser, I want to run IRB within the debugger and see what the content of the page is when the test is running. My test executes `visit sponsor_path(sponsor)`. Is there a way to fetch the content of that route/path in IRB?

Comment: It would help to know which testing framework you are using. If you are using rspec + capybara, use `save_and_open_page` after you visit the sponsor_path

Comment: @doesterr can you add this suggestion as an answer? That worked great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using rspec and capybara, you can have a look at the page with `save_and_open_page`

Call it after you `visit` a path, and it will save the current page (much like doing a save from your browser) and open it.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform html requests through the rails console like this:

```
app.get("/my_url/1")
html = app.response.body
```

Comment: That produces this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method \`get'`

Comment: If I simply run `rails console` from the command line in my app and enter that, it works. However, it doesn't work from within IRB inside the debugger.